# RXJS Pipe not listening to changes on oberservable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angularfire2

Im trying to code an `authGuard`. This is my code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

    return this.auth.user.pipe(
        map(user => {
            if (user) {
                console.log('ok');
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log('denied');
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return false;
            }
        })
    );
}
}
```

In my `authService` I have the user: `Observable<User>;`.

The problem is, the `authGuard` does only check once when the user is loaded if it is null or not. When the guard return true and allows the page to be visited it does not update once the user changes. So when I logout and the user `oberservable` is null, the guard should return false and redirect to the login page but that does not work.

So I can I make `pipe` to listen to changes of its `observable`?

Comment: can you show us your route configuration?

Comment: @PratapA.K sure, its simple: `{ path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }`. On this ProfileComponent I have a button to logout.

Comment: @sychd so are you saying my pipe operation would listen to changes outside of a guard and it can't listen for changes inside a guard? That sounds weird for me...

Comment: If your intension is to implement logout functionality, then usually you will redirect user to login from auth service and not from inside the guard. Job of Auth guard is to check if user logged in or not

Comment: What does the implementation of `AuthService` look like?